# Inner class Java

Tags: java, android

Good evening. I have some troubles with getting response.
I have two classes:
MyHttpClient with method get(), and String for response.

```
public class MyHttpClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://pgu.com";
private static String response;

private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

 public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
 }

 private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
      return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
  }

public static String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public static void setResponse(String response) {
    response = response;
}
```

}

In second class I'm using GET method. Html is printing in LogCat, but setResponse doesn't work. How can I get the response String as a field of MyHttpClient ?

```
public class MyHttpClientUsage {


public MyHttpClientUsage(){

}

public void getInfoAbout() throws HttpException{

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("a", "Static");
    params.put("content", "47");

    MyHttpClient.get("", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
         @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                System.out.println(response);   
                            //Write HTML in LogCat(work) 
                MyHttpClient.setResponse(response); //doesn't work
            }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: *"I have three classes: MyHttpClient with method get(), and String for response."* I can only count 2 here...

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. 2 classes

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more information if the answer below isn't appropriate :)

Answer (score 4):

you need to use `this.response = response` in `MyHttpClient` as currently you are just resetting the parameter that you're sending into the method.

It's good practice to set your method parameters as `final` to avoid this.

Comment: it is called `variable shadowing` by the way

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking wrong, but I can't use <code>this.response = response</code> cause field is static. And I can't use non-static field in static class.

Comment: It shouldn't be static, but just access it directly MyHttpClient.response.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov thank you very much, I didn't know it had a formal name :)